# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'doLogin' was called on null

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am a newbie of Flutter as my name states, i need some help from you guys. I am working with my login, registration form. When I register it throws no error, however when I try to login it shows null error:

```
class AuthDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthDialogState createState() => _AuthDialogState();
}

class _AuthDialogState extends State<AuthDialog> {
  TextEditingController textControllerEmail;
  FocusNode textFocusNodeEmail;
  bool _isEditingEmail = false;

  TextEditingController textControllerPassword;
  FocusNode textFocusNodePassword;
  bool _isEditingPassword = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;

  bool _isRegistering = false;
  bool _isLoggingIn = false;

  String loginStatus;
  Color loginStringColor = Colors.green;

  final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  LoginPagePresenter _presenter;

  String _validateEmail(String value) {
    value = value.trim();

    if (textControllerEmail.text.isNotEmpty) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Email can\'t be empty';
      } else if (!value.contains(RegExp(
          r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"))) {
        return 'Enter a correct email address';
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  void _submit() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
        form.save();
        var user = new User(
            textControllerEmail.text, textControllerPassword.text, null);
        var db = new DatabaseHelper();
        db.saveUser(user);
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void _login() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
        form.save();
        _presenter.doLogin(
            textControllerEmail.text, textControllerPassword.text);
      });
    }
  }

  String _validatePassword(String value) {
    value = value.trim();

    if (textControllerEmail.text.isNotEmpty) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Password can\'t be empty';
      } else if (value.length < 6) {
        return 'Length of password should be greater than 6';
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    textControllerEmail = TextEditingController();
    textControllerPassword = TextEditingController();
    textControllerEmail.text = '';
    textControllerPassword.text = '';
    textFocusNodeEmail = FocusNode();
    textFocusNodePassword = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Container(
            width: 400,
            color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'NORTHERN NOMAD',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.color,
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      letterSpacing: 3,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0,
                    bottom: 8,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Email address',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.color,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      // fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      // letterSpacing: 3,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0,
                    right: 20,
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: textFocusNodeEmail,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    controller: textControllerEmail,
                    autofocus: false,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isEditingEmail = true;
                      });
                    },
                    onSubmitted: (value) => textControllerEmail.text = value,
                    //onSubmitted: (value) {
                    //textFocusNodeEmail.unfocus();
                    //FocusScope.of(context)
                    //.requestFocus(textFocusNodePassword);
                    // },
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
                          width: 3,
                        ),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                      ),
                      hintText: "Email",
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      errorText: _isEditingEmail
                          ? _validateEmail(textControllerEmail.text)
                          : null,
                      errorStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0,
                    bottom: 8,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Password',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2.color,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      // letterSpacing: 3,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 20.0,
                            right: 20,
                          ),
                          child: TextField(
                            focusNode: textFocusNodePassword,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                            controller: textControllerPassword,
                            obscureText: true,
                            autofocus: false,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _isEditingPassword = true;
                              });
                            },
                            onSubmitted: (value) =>
                                textControllerPassword.text = value,
                            //onSubmitted: (value) {
                            //textFocusNodePassword.unfocus();
                            //FocusScope.of(context)
                            //.requestFocus(textFocusNodePassword);
                            //},
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
                                  width: 3,
                                ),
                              ),
                              filled: true,
                              hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                              ),
                              hintText: "Password",
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              errorText: _isEditingPassword
                                  ? _validatePassword(
                                      textControllerPassword.text)
                                  : null,
                              errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12,
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                    ),
                //end
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          width: double.maxFinite,
                          child: TextButton(
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _login();
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 15.0,
                                bottom: 15.0,
                              ),
                              child: _isLoggingIn
                                  ? SizedBox(
                                      height: 16,
                                      width: 16,
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        strokeWidth: 2,
                                        valueColor:
                                            new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                          Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Text(
                                      'Log in',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          width: double.maxFinite,
                          child: TextButton(
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              ),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _submit();
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 15.0,
                                bottom: 15.0,
                              ),
                              child: _isRegistering
                                  ? SizedBox(
                                      height: 16,
                                      width: 16,
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        strokeWidth: 2,
                                        valueColor:
                                            new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                          Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Text(
                                      'Sign up',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                loginStatus != null
                    ? Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: 20.0,
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            loginStatus,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: loginStringColor,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              // letterSpacing: 3,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 40.0,
                    right: 40.0,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 1,
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error when I run login:

> ════════ Exception caught by gesture
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: The method
> 'doLogin' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling:
> doLogin("SIGNIN@gmail.com", "asdsadsad")

Here is my separated .dart file for doLogin

```
abstract class LoginPageContract {
  void onLoginSuccess(User user);
  void onLoginError(String error);
}

class LoginPagePresenter {
  LoginPageContract _view;
  RestData api = new RestData();
  LoginPagePresenter(this._view);

//Simulator login
  doLogin(String email, String password) {
    api
        .login(email, password)
        .then((user) => _view.onLoginSuccess(user))
        .catchError((onError) => _view.onLoginError(onError));
  }
}
```

Comment: You declare "_presenter" and then you call "_presenter.doLogin()", but at no particular stage have you initialised "_presenter" as a "new" LoginPagePresenter object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you call LoginPagePresenter class's constructor method?

Before

```
LoginPagePresenter _presenter;
```

After

```
LoginPagePresenter _presenter = LoginPagePresenter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the _presenter object

```
LoginPagePresenter _presenter = LoginPagePresenter();
```